# Pull Specific Nodes into Array on JSON - Via jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, json, append

I hope this is a simple noober question. I've never really played with JSON at all. I had my document working with an XML pull, but I'm struggling trying to get this to parse correctly via a JSON request.

I'll make the problem I'm having as simple as possible. Here are two sample entries from a JSON document I'm pulling:

```
{
  "completed_in":0.386,
  "query":"%23c2alerts",
  "results":[
     {
        "author":{
           "namespace":"user",
           "name":"nichazel",
           "string_form":"user:nichazel",
           "full_name":"Nicholas Hazel"
        },
        "body":"Have an idea? We are trying to collect new and fresh ideas for process improvement. Please jot down ANY ideas you may have. We will discuss them in our team meeting this afternoon -urgent #c2alerts",
        "topics":[
           {
              "namespace":"hashtag",
              "name":"c2alerts",
              "string_form":"hashtag:c2alerts"
           }
        ],
        "source":"web",
        "post_id":"30d97e00-596f-4936-ade9-557db0e907df",
        "created":"2013-07-31T20:18:22Z",
        "votes":{
           "up_votes":2,
           "down_votes":0,
           "up_voters":[
              {
                 "namespace":"user",
                 "name":"bostrom",
                 "string_form":"user:bostrom"
              },
              {
                 "namespace":"user",
                 "name":"eakerry",
                 "string_form":"user:eakerry"
              }
           ],
           "down_voters":[

           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "author":{
           "namespace":"user",
           "name":"chayavic",
           "string_form":"user:chayavic",
           "full_name":"Sam Chayavichitsilp"
        },
        "body":"Happy Friday C2. Retail AHOD (L2) - No Stand-Up Meeting for the entire team.\n#c2alerts",
        "topics":[
           {
              "namespace":"hashtag",
              "name":"c2alerts",
              "string_form":"hashtag:c2alerts"
           }
        ],
        "source":"web",
        "post_id":"a05d96ae-2c6e-4054-989f-d25a74bfc553",
        "created":"2013-07-26T14:57:18Z"
     }
  ]
}
```

Let's pretend I simply want to append "name" and "body" to an HTML doc. I'm struggling trying to figure out how to make an array with only portions of the JSON document.

Javascript:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $.getJSON('json.json',function(data){
            console.log( "Name: " + name[0].name );
            console.log( "Body: " + body[0].body );

        });
</script>
```

I know this is not anything functional, but how do I define which portions I want to collect in an array so I can define them as variables? ANY help is appreciated, as all of the W3C Schools and forums I've read don't seem to identify the simple methods such as this.

Perfect example:

Name: nichazel
Body: Have an idea? We are trying to collect new and fresh ideas for process improvement. Please jot down ANY ideas you may have. We will discuss them in our team meeting this afternoon -urgent #c2alerts

Name: chayavic
Body: Happy Friday C2. Retail AHOD (L2) - No Stand-Up Meeting for the entire team. #c2alerts

Comment: Try doing `console.log('data')` and try to play around with the data. To get you started, the first name field is `data.results[0].author.name`

Comment: Wow, I knew it was super simple and dumb :-P Nice answer sir. Works like a charm:
<br />
<br />
**bold**
<br />console.log(data.results[1].author.name);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first result's `name` and `body`, then you would need to do this:

```
results[0].author.name;
results[0].body;
```

To loop through all of the results, then do this:

```
$.each(data.results, function(i, item) {
    alert(item.author.name);
    alert(item.body);
});​
```

Comment: Easiest answer ever, perfect. Thanks!!! (I knew it was a dumb question, I just didn't understand the structure was so readily implementable).